# malloc() not showing up in System Monitor

Tags: memory, malloc, monitoring, allocation

I wrote a program which only purpose was to allocate a given amount of memory so that I could see its effect on the Ubuntu 12.04 System Monitor.
This is what I wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc<2)
        exit(-1);

    int *mem=0;
    int kB = 1024*atoi(argv[1]);

    mem = malloc(kB);

    if(mem==NULL)
        exit(-2);

    sleep(3);

    free(mem);
    exit(0);
}
```

I used `sleep()` so that the program would not end immediately so that System Monitor would have time to show the change in memory.
What happens (and I'm puzzled about) is that even if I allocate 1GB, the System Monitor shows no memory change at all! Why is that so?

I thought the reason could be because the allocated memory was never accessed so I tried to insert the following before `sleep()`

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<kB/sizeof(int); i++)
    mem[i]=i;
```

But this too had no effect on the graph in System Monitor.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization?

Comment: Try adding `printf("%d\n", mem[982]);` after the sleep.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, I'm using no optimization at all. I'm just using ` gcc -ansi -Wall`. Also, using a printf to access a memory position after sleep() does not change the result...

Comment: Ok, then your problem isn't caused by the optimizer removing unnessary code.